# How do I make a histogram that shows numbers of assaults by school level?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with three columns. One column has the name of a school in an area. The second column has the school level (elementary, middle, or high school). The third column has the number of assaults that have taken place at each school. How could I make a histogram with this information in R? Here is my code:

```
hist_math2 <- ggplot(data=philadelphia.schools$SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME, aes(x=Assaults)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, color="black", fill = "blue") +  
  xlim(0,80) +
  ylim(0,35) +
  xlab("number of schools") + 
  ylab("Assaults")
  facet_wrap(~ SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME)
hist_math2
```

[Here is what it looks like when I run the code, but instead of number of schools at the bottom, I was thinking it would be better to have school levels? I'm open to any suggestions about how to organize it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo6cQ.png)

Dataset looks like this:

```
| School_Name | School_Level| Assaults|
---------------------------------------
|JFK High Sch | High School |   45    |
---------------------------------------
|JFK Middle Sc| Middle Schoo|   22    |
______________________________________
```

here is the dput!:

```
structure(list(School_code = c(1010L, 1020L, 1030L, 1050L, 
1100L
), Attendance = c(84L, 81L, 90L, 91L, 81L), Enrollment = 
c(1155L, 
854L, 419L, 286L, 611L), New_student = c(177L, 146L, 9L, 6L, 
99L), Withdrawals = c(232L, 181L, 38L, 13L, 110L), 
African_American = c(92L, 
98L, 90L, 96L, 98L), White = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), Asian = 
c(4L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Latino = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), Other = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Pacific_Islander = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Low_income_family = c(86L, 
88L, 86L, 80L, 88L), SCHOOL_NAME_1 = c("JOHN BARTRAM HIGH 
SCHOOL", 
"WEST PHILADELPHIA HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL OF THE FUTURE", 
"PAUL ROBESON HIGH SCHOOL", "SAYRE HIGH SCHOOL"), SCHOOL_NAME_2 
= c("BARTRAM, JOHN HIGH", 
"WEST PHILADELPHIA HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL OF THE FUTURE", 
"ROBESON, PAUL HIGH SCHOOL", "SAYRE, WILLIAM L. HIGH SCHOOL"), 
ADDRESS = c("2401 S. 67TH ST.", "4901 CHESTNUT ST.", "4021 
PARKSIDE AVE.", 
"4125 LUDLOW ST.", "5800 WALNUT ST."), SCHOOL_ZIP = c(19142L, 
19139L, 19104L, 19104L, 19139L), ZIP_PLUS_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), CITY = c("PHILADELPHIA", "PHILADELPHIA", 
"PHILADELPHIA", 
"PHILADELPHIA", "PHILADELPHIA"), STATE_CD = c("PA", "PA", 
"PA", "PA", "PA"), PHONE_NUMBER = c(2154926450, 2154712902, 
2158235502, 2158238207, 2154712904), SCH_START_GRADE = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), SCH_TERM_GRADE = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
), HPADDR = c("", "www.philasd.org/schools/westphila", 
"www.philasd.org/schools/hsof", 
"www.philasd.org/schools/robeson", 
"www.philasd.org/schools/sayre"
), SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME = c("HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH 
SCHOOL", 
"HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL"), Drugs = c(10L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 
4L), Morals = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Assaults = c(31L, 25L, 
14L, 4L, 30L), Weapons = c(10L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 6L), Thefts = c(3L, 
3L, 6L, 1L, 2L), Total_suspensions = c(176L, 250L, 81L, 38L, 
200L), One_suspension = c(137L, 150L, 60L, 28L, 123L), 
Two_suspensions = c(28L, 
58L, 15L, 8L, 45L), Three_suspensions = c(5L, 24L, 4L, 2L, 
20L), Three_plus_suspensions = c(6L, 17L, 2L, 1L, 12L), 
Teacher_attendance = c(94L, 
93L, 95L, 93L, 92L), Special_education = c(21L, 20L, 14L, 
12L, 20L), Gifted_education = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), 
English_second_language = c(9L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 0L), Average_salary = c(72346L, 63537L, 63623L, 
70837L, 68200L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Here is the new dput:

```
structure(list(SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME = c("HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH 
SCHOOL", 
"HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL", "MIDDLE SCHOOL", 
"HIGH SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"MIDDLE SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL"), Assaults = c(31L, 25L, 14L, 
4L, 30L, 10L, 2L, 33L, 22L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 
15L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 6L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 11L, 3L, 51L)), 
row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey mate, if you provide a sample of your data it is easier for people to work on it for you

Comment: Why Assaults is in x axis and the label of x axis is number of schools?

Comment: @LuccaNielsen good catch, I switched the two around! Thanks

Comment: If you want assaults by school level isn't it then a bar plot you want? Or do you want a histogram of assaults per each school level?

Comment: @RuiBarradas It doesn't have to be a histogram, just a way to visualize the data. A bar plot could work!

Comment: @LuizZ Sorry, I am new. Do you know how I could do that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73837858/edit) with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (instead of `df` use the data.frame name).

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think I figured out how to do this and added it to the question

Comment: Thanks for the data. But it  now has many columns not in the question, can you repost but this time the output of `dput(head(texas.schools[c("SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME", "Assaults")], 30))`? **Also**, try adding `facet_wrap(~ SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME)` to the end of your plot code.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added the new dput at the bottom of the question. I added the facet_wrap to the end of my plot code, but what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @hd3_ See if my answer below explains what is `facet_wrap` meant for.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, try this to get a bar plot of the number of assaults by school level, which it sounds like you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

texas.schools %>%
  # group by level to get a sum of the assaults at elem, middle, high
  group_by(School_Level) %>%
  summarise(assaults = sum(Assaults, na.rm = T)) %>%
  # get rid of grouping
  ungroup() %>%
  # now plot the data with bars, change the x and y as needed
  ggplot(aes(x=School_Level, y=assaults)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I am guessing there are too many schools in the data to make it useful to plot those on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of plotting the counts of schools by number of assaults, with a panel per type of school. The type of school must be coerced to factor with the levels in the correct order, if not `ggplot` would put them in alphabetic order and `"HIGH"` would come before `"MIDDLE"`.

I have used a bar plot. If you want to change this, uncomment the `geom_histogram` line and comment out the `geom_bar` one.

And with a small data set, there is no need to set `xlim` and `ylim`.

```r
texas.schools <-
  structure(list(
    SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME = c("HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL", 
                          "HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL", "MIDDLE SCHOOL", 
                          "HIGH SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
                          "ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "MIDDLE SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL"), 
    Assaults = c(31L, 25L, 14L, 4L, 30L, 10L, 2L, 33L, 22L, 5L, 8L, 
                 1L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 6L, 18L, 
                 17L, 19L, 11L, 3L, 51L)), 
    row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")


library(ggplot2)

levls <- c("ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "MIDDLE SCHOOL", "HIGH SCHOOL")

texas.schools |>
  dplyr::mutate(SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME = factor(SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME, levels = levls)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Assaults)) +
  #geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, color = "black", fill = "blue") +
  geom_bar(color = "black", fill = "blue") +
  #xlim(0,80) +
  #ylim(0,35) +
  xlab("Assaults") +
  ylab("number of schools") + 
  facet_wrap(~ SCHOOL_LEVEL_NAME) -> hist_math2

hist_math2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>